# Code For Decrypting with hill cipher algorthm

Tags: android, encryption

This is the code for decrypting, but it isnt work. Can you help me? I didnt know why this code didnt work. The image decryption still working, but i got only more worse image. First time i think my code for encrypt and decrypt error, but when i learn it more, it seems good. No error there. I got stuck sir, i dont know why the image cant be decrypt. Please be my savior.

```
package com.drag0nathz.dekripimage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    EditText editText13, editText11;
    Button btnDekrip, button12;
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private String userChoosenTask;
    private Bitmap operation, bmp;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream;
    //FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;
    String logMerah = "log warna merah program ini : ";
    String logHijau = "log warna hijau program ini : ";
    String logBiru = "log warna biru program ini : ";
    String char_db = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int[][] M_key = new int[3][3];
    int[][] M_inverse = new int [3][3];
    int i;
    String key_input, ciphertext, keyinversechar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        editText13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == button12){
                    key_input = editText11.getText().toString();
                    if (key_input.length() < 9)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "panjang kunci harus 9 karakter!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if (key_input.length() > 9){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "panjang kunci harus 9 karakter!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        check_kunci(key_input);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        btnDekrip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDekrip);
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) ivImage.getDrawable();
        bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
    }

    public void check_kunci(String kunci){

        Toast.makeText(this, kunci  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        char[] array_kunci = kunci.toCharArray();

        int j = 0;

        while ( j < array_kunci.length){
            for (int x=0; x <3; x++){
                for (int y=0; y<3; y++){
                    M_key[x][y] = char_db.indexOf(array_kunci[j]);
                    j = j+1;
                }
            }
        }

        int d = determinant(M_key);
        d = d %256;
        if (d == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kunci invalid karena determinant = 0"   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (d % 2 == 0 || d % 13 == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kunci invalid karena determinan memiliki persamaan faktor dgn 256"   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kunci Valid, multiplication inverse " + mi(d)   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            M_inverse = getInverse(M_key, mi(d));
            int newArray[] = new int[M_inverse.length*M_inverse[0].length];
            for (int m = 0; m < M_inverse.length; m++)
            {
                int [] row = M_inverse[m];
                for (int n = 0; n < row.length; n++)
                {
                    int number = M_inverse[m][n];
                    newArray[m*row.length+n] = number;
                }
            }
            keyinversechar = Arrays.toString(newArray);
            editText13.setText(keyinversechar);
        }
    }
    public void dekrip(View view) {
        bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
        int size = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
        int[] gambarR = new int[size];
        int[] gambarG = new int[size];
        int[] gambarB = new int[size];
        int k = 0;
        int[] matrixGambarMod2R = new int[size];
        int[] matrixGambarMod2G = new int[size];
        int[] matrixGambarMod2B = new int[size];
        int[] matrixGambarMod1R = new int[size];
        int[] matrixGambarMod1G = new int[size];
        int[] matrixGambarMod1B = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++) {
                int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
                gambarR[k] = Color.red(p);
                gambarG[k] = Color.green(p);
                gambarB[k] = Color.blue(p);
                k++;
            }
        }

        if(size % 3 == 2){
            for(int i = 0; i< matrixGambarMod2R.length-2;i=i+3){
                //merah
                matrixGambarMod2R[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod2R[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod2R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod2R[i+2]) % 256;
                matrixGambarMod2R[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod2R[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod2R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod2R[i+2]) % 256;
                matrixGambarMod2R[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod2R[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod2R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod2R[i+2]) % 256;


                //hijau
                matrixGambarMod2G[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod2G[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod2G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod2G[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod2G[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod2G[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod2G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod2G[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod2G[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod2G[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod2G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod2G[i+2]) % 256;


                //biru
                matrixGambarMod2B[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod2B[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod2B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod2B[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod2B[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod2B[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod2B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod2B[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod2B[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod2B[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod2B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod2B[i+2]) % 256;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i< size;i++){
                gambarR[i] = matrixGambarMod2R[i];
                gambarG[i] = matrixGambarMod2G[i];
                gambarB[i] = matrixGambarMod2B[i];
            }
        }
        //else if (size % 3 == 1) -> tambah array diujung
        if(size % 3 == 1){
            for(int i = 0; i< matrixGambarMod1R.length-1;i=i+3){
                //merah
                matrixGambarMod1R[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod1R[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod1R[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod1R[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]) % 256;
                //hijau
                matrixGambarMod1G[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod1G[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod1G[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod1G[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]) % 256;
                //biru
                matrixGambarMod1B[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod1B[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod1B[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod1B[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]) % 256;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i< size;i++){
                gambarR[i] = matrixGambarMod1R[i];
                gambarG[i] = matrixGambarMod1G[i];
                gambarB[i] = matrixGambarMod1B[i];
            }

        }

        if(size % 3 == 0){
            matrixGambarMod1R = gambarR;
            matrixGambarMod1G = gambarG;
            matrixGambarMod1B = gambarB;
            for(int i = 0; i< matrixGambarMod1R.length;i=i+3){
                //merah
                matrixGambarMod1R[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod1R[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod1R[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod1R[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod1R[i+2]) % 256;

                //hijau
                matrixGambarMod1G[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod1G[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod1G[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod1G[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod1G[i+2]) % 256;

                //biru
                matrixGambarMod1B[i]= (M_inverse[0][0]* matrixGambarMod1B[i]+
                        M_inverse[0][1]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[0][2]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]= (M_inverse[1][0]* matrixGambarMod1B[i]+
                        M_inverse[1][1]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[1][2]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]) % 256;

                matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]= (M_inverse[2][0]* matrixGambarMod1B[i]+
                        M_inverse[2][1]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+1]+
                        M_inverse[2][2]* matrixGambarMod1B[i+2]) % 256;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i< size;i++){
                gambarR[i] = matrixGambarMod1R[i];
                gambarG[i] = matrixGambarMod1G[i];
                gambarB[i] = matrixGambarMod1B[i];
            }

        }
        int l = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<bmp.getHeight();j++){
                operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(gambarR[l], gambarG[l], gambarB[l]));
                l++;
            }
        }
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(operation);
    }


    public int determinant(int[][] A){

        int res;

        res = A[0][0]*A[1][1]*A[2][2] + A[0][1]*A[1][2]*A[2][0] + A[0][2]*A[1][0]*A[2][1] - A[2][0]*A[1][1]*A[0][2] - A[2][1]*A[1][2]*A[0][0] - A[2][2]*A[1][0]*A[0][1];

        return res;
    }

    public int[][] getInverse(int key[][], int mi){
        int i,j;
        int[][] kofaktor = new int[3][3];
        int[][] key_inv = new int[3][3];
        int d = determinant(M_key);
        mi = mi(d % 256);
        if (mi<0)
            mi += 256;

        kofaktor[0][0] = (key[1][1]*key[2][2]-key[1][2]*key[2][1]);
        kofaktor[0][1] = -1 * (key[1][0]*key[2][2]-key[1][2]*key[2][0]);
        kofaktor[0][2] = (key[1][0]*key[2][1]-key[1][1]*key[2][0]);
        kofaktor[1][0] = -1 * (key[0][1]*key[2][2]-key[0][2]*key[2][1]);
        kofaktor[1][1] = (key[0][0]*key[2][2]-key[0][2]*key[2][0]);
        kofaktor[1][2] = -1 * (key[0][0]*key[2][1]-key[0][1]*key[2][0]);
        kofaktor[2][0] = (key[0][1]*key[1][2]-key[0][2]*key[1][1]);
        kofaktor[2][1] = -1 * (key[0][0]*key[1][2]-key[0][2]*key[1][0]);
        kofaktor[2][2] = (key[0][0]*key[1][1]-key[0][1]*key[1][0]);

        key_inv[0][0] = ((kofaktor[0][0]));
        key_inv[0][1] = ((kofaktor[1][0]));
        key_inv[0][2] = ((kofaktor[2][0]));
        key_inv[1][0] = ((kofaktor[0][1]));
        key_inv[1][1] = ((kofaktor[1][1]));
        key_inv[1][2] = ((kofaktor[2][1]));
        key_inv[2][0] = ((kofaktor[0][2]));
        key_inv[2][1] = ((kofaktor[1][2]));
        key_inv[2][2] = ((kofaktor[2][2]));

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (key_inv[i][j] < 0)
                    key_inv[i][j] += 256;
                key_inv[i][j] *= mi;
                key_inv[i][j] %= 256;
            }
        }
        return key_inv;
    }

    public int mi(int d)
    {
        int q,r1,r2,r,t1,t2,t;
        r1=256;
        r2=d;
        t1=0;
        t2=1;

        while(r1!=1&&r2!=0)
        {
            q=r1/r2;
            r=r1%r2;
            t=t1-(t2*q);
            r1=r2;
            r2=r;
            t1=t2;
            t2=t;
        }
        return (t1+t2);
    }


}
```

Comment: This is at least the fourth time in a few days that you post a bunch of irrelevant code. And even without encryption. What you have to do instead has been said to you already very clearly. So do that!

Comment: sir im sorry, im doing the editing code in my question before. i will tag you, i have post all my code. now you can debug, and get the error. help me please, im sorry for my mistake.

Comment: We do not need or want all your code, we need a [mcve].

Comment: @zaph Sir, if i know wheres the error why i didnt get the original image, i wont post all of my code. i post it all, so you can run and test. and maybe you can help me find the error.

Comment: You are asking for a lower quality image with `thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);`  so you get a lower quality image .. Use a loosless format like PNG if you don't want to lose quality in the image..